# Change OG Group River of News Per Group Basis?

Tags: views, organic-groups

Hello i was wondering the best way on how to go about this. I was thinking of creating a text field for my group content type and changing the url and then adding differant block views to urls like-

blog/*
forum/*
etc

Blog will show a blog view and a forum view on forum. I dont really want to mess about with my urls though.

I dont really want to have differant Group Content Types either.

What would be the best if i could have a text select list on the Group Content Type

blog
forum
etc

and the view will change depending on the choice.

Can anyone think of a way of doing this? I think i need to bring in some relatonship for my new text field but itdoesnt seem to be happening for me.

Thanks

Comment: i know i can do it with Panels but i dont want to ue Panels. TVI does what im after for taxonomy. Something similar for OG would be ideal.thanks. Ive got EVA there and im playing about with that with not much success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

heh heh i bloody done it!

Relationships
OG membership: OG membership from Node
(OG membership from node) OG membership: Group Node from OG membership

Filter criteria
(Group node from OG membership) Content: Placetype (= Blog)